# Incoming email attachments missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, attachments, incoming-email, announcements

I have a SharePoint farm in 2013 in which I am using incoming email functionality.

We have configured Announcement list to receive email and when sending an email from my Gmail account everything is working. Attachments are also getting attached separately to the list item like excel files, images or work file.

When I am sending an email from my official mailbox I can see only originalmessage.eml file. no other attachments are visible.

Am I missing something

Comment: When you say your 'official' mailbox is that one that's on an Exchange server that shares a domain with SharePoint? The email addresses in SP are obviously getting published externally OK if Gmail works, but I would guess (and this is a long shot) that there's some difference in the Exchange send/receive relays for internal and external that might be stripping attachments (usually Exchange will have one specifically for SharePoint). You could try watching the Drop folder where the SMTP server SP uses is and grab the email to check if it has the attachment, but the problem is after that I think

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your response. when we are sending email from gmail we receive eml file in drop folder and when the same reaches SharePoint announcement list we have eml file attached to the item along with if there are other attachemtnst in email like image/excel those are also attached to the item.

Comment: Where is the 'official' mailbox you mentioned hosted? Is it on an Exchange server that shares a domain name with SharePoint?

Comment: yes it is on an exchange server and has the same domain name as SharePoint

Comment: In that case I think you need to involve your Exchange admins. It is possible that the specific send connector set up for SharePoint (there should be one) is stripping the attachments, but the one that handles mail from all other public domains isn't. It's a long shot but that's all I can think of.